# Downloading File using TDownloadURL fails unless app is run as Administrator

Tags: delphi

My app has a function which uses TDownloadURL to down load some PDF files. It works perfectly when run from the D:\ drive but the only way I can get it to work from C:\Program Files is to run it as an Administrator.  It there a way round this or are there alternative functions I could use to resolve this?

Comment: Have you looked at f.i. https://superuser.com/questions/1031275/windows-allow-normal-non-elevated-programs-to-write-to-program-files-director?

Comment: Don't download the files into the app directory. Use another one, such as the temp directory.

Comment: Unless TDownloadURL is saving data to the Program Files directory I cannot see why it should be blocked.  I have a  temporary file which the DownloadURL saves to but that is in AppData\MyApp. Even with when  its in a file on another drive it fails to download.

Comment: How do browsers manage to download running from Program Files(x86)?

Comment: Perhaps TDownloadURL stores a temporary copy in the same directory as the .EXE file (it shouldn't) and when finally downloaded all of it, moves it to where you have specified it should go? The issues you're having is pointing very strongly in the direction that somewhere along the process, it is attempting to store something or other in the same directory as the .EXE file is located...

Comment: *How do browsers manage* - By not **writing** to Program Files. No browser downloads files into the Program Files folder structure. They download by default to the user's Downloads folder, which is under C:\Users\YourUserName. No application should be writing to Program Files except the installer that installed the app, and that installer is required to be run under an aministrative account during the installation process.

Comment: Correction, saving it to D:\ doesn't work but saving it to MYDOCUMENTS does work.

Comment: @KenWhite is completely correct.  You shouldn't find it too difficult to adjust the access permissions on drive D: to allow writing to it, but the fact that you are having trouble with it makes me wonder if there's something a bit odd about your set-up, because ime writing to D: should "just work".

Comment: @MartynA: It appears that it works from D:\ correctly but not from C:\Program Files (x86). This leads me to believe that the file is being downloaded into the application's own directory, which won't work when that directory is Program Files. The proper solution is to not save the files to the app's folder in the first place, but to put them in the proper location (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local) or C:\Users\Public\. I don't think that changing permissions in Program FIles (x86) is a proper solution.

Comment: @KenWhite:  I completely agree about Program Files and Program Files (x86).  I was only commenting in the OP's apparent difficulty writind to his D: drive ...

Comment: @MartynA: Yeah, but the problem isn't on the D: drive. The OP says it works perfectly when run from D:, but won't work from C:\Program Files (x86). :-)

Comment: Looking a the documentation http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.ExtActns.TDownLoadURL please take in account the bottom note: `You should assign a value to the URL property and the and to the Filename property...`, where the latter is the one you should not assign to a file inside your application folder.